# Templates - condition upon listed parameters

Tags: c++, c++11

How do I do what the comment wants?

```
template<typename T1, typename T2=int>
struct foo
{
  //only define foo function if T2 was explictly listed by client
  //(even if it was explictly listed as int)
  //what should be inside "enable_if"?
  foo(T1 t1, T2 t2){}
};
```

Comment: You cant' distinguish whether an argument was explicitly provided or not. You have to define two different templates

Comment: @AndyProwl What I want to do is create a member variable for T2 (and corresponding function) if it was specified but skip the member and function otherwise. Is there any room for code reuse here or do I have to duplicate all the T1 related things in both templates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't set `T2` to `int`.  Instead, set it to `MagicFlagTypeThatNobodyElseIsSupposedToUse`.

Then, in your `template`, create a `typedef blahblah RealT2`, where `blahblah` resolves to `int` if `T2` is `MagicFlagTypeThatNobodyElseIsSupposedToUse`, and `T2` otherwise.  (You have to implement `blahblah` yourself, it is a really easy traits class).

Then use `RealT2` in your code.  You can detect if `T2` was passed in if `RealT2` is the same as `T2`.  Use standard tricks to add/remove methods based on a compile time boolean condition (usually via inheritance), or use SFINAE to block anyone matching your method.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a struct with a different composition depending on different template arguments you're probably looking for variadic templates in C++11

http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/EhvU7k9E/